# Tensorflow - predict() not showing the prediction output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to predict based on single instance but not what I wanted.

```
predictions = est.predict(input_fn=["male", 22, 1, 0, 7.25, "Third", "unknown", "Southampton", "n"])
print(predictions)
```

Output

```
<generator object Estimator.predict at 0x136c3cf48>
```

What I want either `Y` or `N`.

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/ML_python/blob/master/lab_2.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Youre passing a wrong type of argument as `input_fn`. This parameter is supposed to be a function that returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object. Look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/premade#create_input_functions) link from the tensorflow documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as said by @Mohammad hp, the argument for `input_fn` should be a function that construct the features. Check the official documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict .

Also, try to print the result like this, if `print(predictions)` does not work:

```py
print(next(predictions))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).